# p:selectOneMenu using a mask in 'editable' mode

Tags: primefaces

The following works

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{f.entrada1}" editable="true">
```

As does

```
<p:inputMask mask="99:99" value="#{f.saida1}">
```

I do not seem to be able to combine the two in some way or add a mask to the editable `p:selectOneMenu` in a different way?

My PrimeFaces version is: ....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Version PrimeFaces 5.3.

Or put a list in inputMask. it's possible?